# Why the following projections of the differential map are $0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, dynamical-systems

Let $p$ be a hyperbolic fixed point for a $C^k$ map $f : U \subset E \to E$, $k \le 1, U$ an open subset of the Banach space $E$. By taking local coordinates, we can assume that the fixed point is $0$ in $E$ and $E = E^s \oplus E^u$. Consider the projections $\pi_s : E \to E^s, \pi_u : E \to E^u$. Using the spitting $E^s \oplus E^u$ we write
$$Df_0 = \begin{pmatrix} A_{ss} & 0 \\ 0 & A_{uu} \end{pmatrix},$$
where $A_{ss} = \pi_s Df_0{_{|(E^s \times \{0\})}}, A_{uu} = \pi_u Df_0{_{|(\{0\} \times E^u)}}$.

I don't undersand why $A_{su} = A_{us} = 0$. Can someone explain me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The splitting is invariant under $Df_0$ and so the components $A_{su}$ and $A_{us}$ vanish.